# npm {package} --save-dev not running at the command line

Tags: node.js, npm

i tried running

```
$npm install mocha --save-dev
```

and then

```
$mocha
```

the result is

```
$-bash: mocha: command not found
```

If install it globally it works but what if I want to use a package version on this project only

Is there a way to make it works without installing it globally?

I am on a mac 10.11 el capitan

Comment: try to change the param order... try this: npm install --save-dev mocha

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24497202/5048383

Comment: i tried it didnt work ,i even triend deleting the node_modules folder

Comment: The answer suggests to install it as a global or to use npm test .. is there a way to make work without it ?

Comment: answer suggests use: `node_modules/.bin/mocha` or `node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha` to run mocha locally or just add `"test": "mocha"` to npm scripts and run locally installed mocha with `npm test` and there is no other way.

Comment: i was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q8Jl85FJz4E&list=PLw5h0DiJ-9PAdZwGJCYb7a9P2mJHayQQ3 and she is able to do it is it no longer available ? (skip to 2:09)

Comment: @Crimeira, It never been available. Video editing magic and she forgot to explain that she has mocha globally installed. some people also complained about that in comments: *`npm install mocha --save-dev` will not give you the commanline, `npm install mocha -g` will do it.*

Comment: thanks for the attention its now clear

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `npx` command to run local dependencies

Try the command:

```
 npx mocha
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you haven't installed mocha globally you have to point terminal to your package's local directory

Run this command instead:

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha
```

this will run the locally installed `mocha` package.

Answer (score -1):

To use a command installed from an NPM package, you have to install it globally. Try:

```
$ npm i -g mocha
```

If you don't want to install it globally, then you can use the local mocha command from:

```
$ <app>/node_modules/.bin/mocha
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ cd project_directory
```

If you already have the dependency in package.json file -> do

```
$ npm install

$ ./node_modules/.bin/<module-name> -V // to get the version
$ ./node_modules/.bin/<module-name> <action> // to use that module
```

else, if you want to install a new module, firstly do ->

```
$ npm install <module-name> --save-dev
```

and then use the commands to get the version and use the module. In this way you will be able to set up and use specific node_modules for a particular project which is a good practice and make your project easy to share.
To install modules globally, run ->

```
$ npm install -g <module-name>
```

or with sudo privileges ->

```
$ sudo npm install -g <module-name>
```

I hope this helps :) :)