# Binary Executables in node_modules are not found in Github Actions Ubuntu Node image

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, github-actions

I have a node webapp that I run locally to run test specs. I use mocha and karma as a spec runner. Here are one of my npm commands to run a test suite:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
   "test-jobs-once-docker": "mocha --reporter spec \"server/**/*.spec.js\""
  }
}
```

When I run docker-compose up locally, the command works and the specs run in the docker container.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:  
  mongo:     
    image: mongo:3.4
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always    
  redis:
    image: redis:7.0.8    
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    restart: always        
  webapp:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - NODE_ENV=dockerTest
    platform: linux/amd64
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - PORT=9000
      - NODE_ENV=dockerTest
      - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379            
    command: ['npm', 'run', 'test-jobs-once-docker']
```

Here is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:20.04

ENV APP_HOME="/app"

WORKDIR /app

USER root
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl \
    && apt-get -y autoclean

ENV NODE_VERSION=12.9.0
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/nvm/ && \
    curl --silent -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.2/install.sh | bash

RUN /bin/bash -c "source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default"

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH

RUN apt-get install python -y
RUN apt-get install libkrb5-dev -y
RUN apt-get install libpng-dev -y 
RUN apt-get install libfontconfig1 fontconfig libfontconfig1-dev -y

RUN apt-get install build-essential  -y

COPY ./package*.json ./
COPY .npmrc ./

RUN npm install
COPY . /app


RUN touch ./server/config/local.env.js

ENV PORT=9000

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 9000
```

However, when I run this in GitHub Actions it says:

> mocha: command not found

Here is my workflow:

```yaml
name: Run Test Suite
on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  run-tests-docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps: 
    - name: Check out code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Build Docker Containers & Run Test Specs
      run:  docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" up -d --build
          
    - name: Run Test Specs
      run:  npm run test-jobs-once-docker
      env:
        NODE_ENV: dockerTest
   
    - name: Stop Containers
      if: always()
      run: docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" down
```

When I run this on GitHub Actions, I comment out the `command` property on the webapp in the `docker-compose.yml` so the command is executed in the job on GitHub Actions instead of when the container builds. I feel like this is the problem. I am not sure how to inspect the container that is built and used in GitHub Actions to see if the `node_modules` exists.

Does anybody know how I can get access to the `mocha` executable so I can run my tests in GitHub Actions?

Update:

I noticed that the `node_modules` folder is not in the directory the rest of my app is in. I'm going to guess this is part of the problem, this is the `$PATH` variable and files in the directory after the environment builds in github actions (also note the `Dockerfile` and `nvm`

```
/home/runner/.local/bin:/opt/pipx_bin:/home/runner/.cargo/bin:/home/runner/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/.ghcup/bin:/home/runner/.dotnet/tools:/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
Dockerfile
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
Procfile
README.md
app.json
bower.json
client
database.json
docker-compose.yml
e2e
karma.conf.js
package-lock.json
package.json
server
shared
webpack-dev.config.js
webpack-production.config.js
webpack.common.js
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722407/how-do-you-install-and-run-mocha-the-node-js-testing-module-getting-mocha-co

Comment: Take a look at the above thread. Looks like an npm version issue. Verify your local npm version. The preinstalled version on `ubnutu-20.04` runner is [npm 9.5.1](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md#package-management). So, it seems like either you have to installed `mocha` manually before using it or you can use `npx mocha` instead.

Comment: @Azeem I doubt most of what's in that thread is relevant exactly. That was from when Node started to standardize on `node_modules/.bin`, a long long time ago, and npm scripts now set that path prefix automatically.

Comment: I don't see anything in your workflows that runs `npm i`. Is that in the Dockerfile referenced by the build step in the compose? If so, you could add an `ls` either in a `RUN` in your Dockerfile, or in the command, to check that they're actually where they're supposed to be.

Comment: Thank you! I added the Dockerfile to the post, that is where I run npm install. I am taking a look at all the suggestions, thanks! I'll let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be related to the context in which the `mocha` command is being executed.

- When you run the `mocha` command inside your Docker container, it has access to the `node_modules` directory that was installed during the Docker build process (since `npm install` is executed in the Dockerfile).
- However, when you try to run `mocha` directly from your GitHub Actions workflow, it does not have access to those `node_modules` as it is outside the Docker container context.

**Make sure that `node_modules` is correctly installed**: If you want to keep running the tests from the GitHub Actions workflow, you could ensure that the `node_modules` directory is correctly installed. You can do this by running `npm install` in your GitHub Actions workflow:

```yaml
- name: Install Dependencies
  run:  npm install

- name: Run Test Specs
  run:  npm run test-jobs-once-docker
  env:
    NODE_ENV: dockerTest
```

However, keep in mind that this might not work if your tests rely on other aspects of your Docker environment that are not replicated in your GitHub Actions runner.

**And make sure the working directory is correct**: Make sure that the GitHub Actions runner is in the correct directory when it tries to run `npm run test-jobs-once-docker`. If it is not in the right directory, it might not find the `node_modules` directory. You can use the `working-directory` option in your GitHub Actions workflow to ensure that the runner is in the correct directory:

```yaml
- name: Run Test Specs
  run:  npm run test-jobs-once-docker
  env:
    NODE_ENV: dockerTest
  working-directory: /path/to/your/app
```

Replace `/path/to/your/app` with the actual path to your app in the runner's filesystem.

---

The alternative approach would be to run the tests within the Docker container**: Instead of trying to run `npm run test-jobs-once-docker` from the GitHub Actions workflow, you could run the tests within the Docker container itself. This would ensure that the `mocha` command has access to the `node_modules` directory. You can do this by modifying your GitHub Actions workflow to execute the command inside the Docker container. Here is an example of how you could do that:

```yaml
- name: Run Test Specs
  run:  docker exec <container-id> npm run test-jobs-once-docker
  env:
    NODE_ENV: dockerTest
```

Note that `<container-id>` should be replaced with the ID or name of your Docker container. You can get this information from the output of `docker-compose up -d --build`.

You can get the container ID of your Docker container by using the `docker ps` command with a filter for the container name. The filter matches on all or part of a container's name.

This is how you could use it in your GitHub Actions workflow:

```yaml
- name: Get Container ID
  run: echo "CONTAINER_ID=$(docker ps -aqf "name=webapp")" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

In this step, the command `docker ps -aqf "name=webapp"` lists all containers and filters for the one named "webapp". The `-aq` flags stand for "all" and "quiet" respectively, meaning the command will return all containers (not just the running ones) and will only print their container IDs.

The `echo "CONTAINER_ID=$(docker ps -aqf "name=webapp")" >> $GITHUB_ENV` command writes the output (the container ID) to the `GITHUB_ENV` file, which makes it available as an environment variable in subsequent steps of the workflow.

You can then use this container ID in subsequent steps like so:

```yaml
- name: Inspect Node Modules
  run: docker exec ${{ env.CONTAINER_ID }} ls -la /app/node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have `mocha` and/or `karma` within your image, so you can run them, in your `Dockerfile` after:

```
RUN npm install
```

add:

```
RUN npm install -g mocha
```

this will make mocha and karma available as commands in your PATH, so you can then run "mocha --reporter spec "server/**/*.spec.js""

Answer (score 0):

the `mocha` command is not found because it is not available in the environment where you try to run it:

```
      run:  npm run test-jobs-once-docker
```

While there is an `npm` command available and the file `package.json` accessible for it, it effectively executes the npm package script called `test-jobs-once-docker`, specifically:

```
mocha --reporter spec "server/**/*.spec.js"
```

The subshell `npm` invokes then is not able to find `mocha` resulting in the error message in question.

---

This just to understand the error message.

---

The rest is not entirely clear from your question. And this effects the environment that you need to execute the `mocha` command line successfully. The fitting environment, which you also confirm working, you specifically reject:

> When I run this on GitHub Actions, I comment out the command property on the webapp in the `docker-compose.yml` so the command is executed in the job on GitHub Actions [...]

The rationale you give:

> so the command is executed in the job on GitHub Actions instead of when the container builds.

And then:

> I feel like this is the problem.

Indeed! The whole setup is done to run this command but then you disable the command because you do the whole setup?

This makes no sense. Indeed you want to run it when it builds, you have this in your pipeline, even named:

> Build Docker Containers & Run Test Specs

Just do it. Don't comment out the command. Otherwise you're starting the container but without running the command. The command you want to run.

```
docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" up -d --build
```

It is either the misunderstanding running the setup in background, or it is fine, but then you need to execute the command in the running container (and keep the command in the compose config commented):

```
docker-compose exec webapp npm run test-jobs-once-docker
```